# Mostrar slide apenas na primeira pagina wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, slide

Boa Tarde, estou com site wordpress que exibi um slide, porém eu queria que ele aparecesse somente na primeira pagina do index, e não nas demais da paginação. Tem como fazer isso?

Codigo do slide:

```
insira o código aqu <div class="slider">
    <div class="owl-carousel">
        <?php $popular = new WP_Query(        
            array(
                'posts_per_page'=> 18,
                'meta_key'=> 'popular_posts', 
                'orderby'=> 'meta_value_num',
                'order'=> 'DESC'
            ));
            while ($popular->have_posts()) : $popular->the_post(); ?>   
                <div class="post min">
                    <div class="thumb">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo leowp_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>  
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>           
        </div>
    </div>i
```

Linha do index que chama o slide `

```
    <main>
    
    
    
<?php require_once("slide.php"); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Para pegar a página atual da paginação você pode usar:

```
$paginaAtual = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

E para validar se vai exibir o slide, pode fazer algo assim:

```
<?php 
    $paginaAtual = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    if($paginaAtual == 1){
        require_once("slide.php");
    }
    
 ?>
```

Comment: Em qual parte eu coloco esse codigo $paginaAtual = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

Comment: Eu coloquei como tem que ficar no segundo trecho de código

Comment: funcionou, obrigado